# Nextjs and redis-om - Entity issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, redis

I am working on search with redis (redis-om) in new NextJS 13 (app directory). When I go by [tutorial](https://redis.io/docs/clients/om-clients/stack-node/) I am getting following error with Entity. I actually don't know if it is bug or I am doing something wrong. Thanks for any advice.

**Code**

```
import { Client, Entity, Schema, Repository } from "redis-om";

const client = new Client();

async function connect() {
  if (!client.isOpen()) {
    console.log("redis url", process.env.REDIS_URL)
    await client.open(process.env.REDIS_URL);
  }
}

class Coin extends Entity {}

let schema = new Schema(
  Coin,
  {
    id: { type: "string"},
    symbol: { type: "string"},
    name: { type: "text", textSearch: true },
  },
  {
    dataStructure: "JSON",
  }
```

**Error**

```
- error lib/redis.ts (14:21) @ Entity
- error Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

This might be caused by a React Class Component being rendered in a Server Component, React Class Components only works in Client Components. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/class-component-in-server-component
```

I tried to use it as a client, but it is not working as well. Also nodejs server could work too, but I would like to keep it in NextJS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial was written for Redis OM 0.2, which is reflected in the package.json. Redis 0.3 should work fine with it.

*However*, Redis OM 0.4 introduced breaking changes which eliminated the Entity class. I'm guessing you entered:

```bash
npm install redis-om
```

This would give you that latest version (i.e 0.4) which isn't compatible with this tutorial.

I would recommend sticking with the upgraded version and checking out the documentation in the [README](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node/) or following this similar but *upgraded* [tutorial](https://github.com/redis-developer/redis-om-node-tutorial).

*Note that I am the author of Redis OM and both tutorials. Updating the example on redis.io is in my backlog.*